# Give internal users access to the customer portal by default?

Tags: permissions, profile, customer-portal, user-management

By default, the customer portal is accessed via portal user accounts. Salesforce internal users have a separate, non-portal contact for logging into Salesforce via a standard SF splash page.

To configure an internal user as a portal user requires giving that user a separate login with a new username and password. This creates confusion and frustration for these users if they wish to switch between normal day to day work in SF, and visiting the portal or helping a customer.

Community users can easily be added to the default access for standard users, but I have not yet found a way to do this for portal access.

What am I missing?

Comment: A customer portal is a completely different site, and also a completely different license type than a standard SF user. A standard user can't just login to a community.

Comment: They can if you set it up in their contact, takes maybe 30s to do but is a different login. Yes it is a different license, but a higher license should be able to have access just like how the communities is setup there.

Comment: The only way you could make this work (super hacky) would be if you have a common unique identifier shared between the current user and the community user they are trying to log in as. Do they share an email address or anything that's unique? Could you make a unique ID that the two separate users share? If so, I can post you up a one click login solution.

Comment: Maybe something like an employee ID???

Comment: @cricketlang yes, they will always have the same email address. I've heard of the method you've described but I'm not sure how it's done, would like to see that thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have internal SF users who also have accounts for your customer portal, and you want an easier way for them to simply login to the customer portal, correct? The common way to do that is using Salesforce as a SSO provider for the community btw, but I have a less "pretty" hack that works as well.

Comment: Correct- and I would like to go that route but am restricted by business rules that force me to push everyone through one portal, making a very easy problem very annoyingly difficult.

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll point you in the right direction of a strategy to help a bit. I'm assuming the internal users have the permissions to log into community as user?

Comment: Yes, but there is a setting for enabling all internal users as community users so that isn't really a problem, only the portal user access doesn't allow the same property.

Comment: The solution I'd post would require that permission on any user who wishes to log into the community this "fast" way without hunting down their respective contact record. Like I said, it's hacky.